# Variable in include file c++

Tags: c++, macros, include, c-preprocessor

I am trying to include files in a cpp, but the filenames should be based on a variable.

In my case, the filenames should be `filename_X.cpp`  where `X` ranges from 0 to 90 and `filename` is a predefined text, i.e. there is in total 90 includes statement. I would like to know if it is possible to

1. Create a loop that includes 90 files
2. Include using a variable filename

From searching through the internet, I have an approach to the point 2) as below:

```
#define FILENAME some_file_name

#define QUOTE(x) _QUOTE(x)
#define _QUOTE(x) #x

#define _CONCAT(x, y) x##_##y.cpp
#define CONCAT(x, y) _CONCAT(x, y)

#define _INCLUDE_FILE(x, y) (QUOTE(CONCAT(x, y)))
#define INCLUDE_FILE(x, y) _INCLUDE_FILE(x, y)

//#include INCLUDE_FILE(FILENAME, 0)
```

which works fine if I am calling a print function

```
printf(INCLUDE_FILE(FILENAME, 70));
```

It will print `some_file_name_70.cpp` .

However, when I try to use it in an include statement `#include INCLUDE_FILE(FILENAME, 0)`, an error shows up as:

```
pred.cpp:22:10: error: expected "FILENAME" or <FILENAME>
#include INCLUDE_FILE(FILENAME, 0)
         ^
pred.cpp:20:28: note: expanded from macro 'INCLUDE_FILE'
#define INCLUDE_FILE(x, y) _INCLUDE_FILE(x, y)
                           ^
pred.cpp:19:29: note: expanded from macro '_INCLUDE_FILE'
#define _INCLUDE_FILE(x, y) (QUOTE(CONCAT(x, y)))
                            ^
1 error generated.
```

Does anyone know why does the error happen? Thank you very much!

Comment: The only sane way is to have a pre-process where some script generates a `gen.h` file which contains a bunch of `#include` directives

Comment: Write a program with a for-loop to output the names to a file. It will take fewer lines than any macro trickery.

Comment: If you actually manage to get the C++ pre-processor to do this, then I'll be thoroughly impressed (and also a bit scared). Better to write a separate program that does the preprocessing and writes a header file that you include, then run that program as part of your build process.

Comment: The `#include INCLUDE_FILE(FILENAME, 0)` expands to `#include ("some_file_name_0.cpp")` which is does not work as a preprocessor include directive parameter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That works for me, if I remove the parenthesis in the `_INCLUDE_FILE` macro:

```
#define FILENAME t

#define QUOTE(x) _QUOTE(x)
#define _QUOTE(x) #x

#define _CONCAT(x, y) x##y.h
#define CONCAT(x, y) _CONCAT(x, y)

#define _INCLUDE_FILE(x, y) QUOTE(CONCAT(x, y))
#define INCLUDE_FILE(x, y) _INCLUDE_FILE(x, y)

#include INCLUDE_FILE(FILENAME,1)

int main (){
}
```

Always take care of parenthesis in macros...

Note that you should not include `.cpp` files. That is not recommended, include only `.h` files. Except if you really know the weird thing your are doing.

Comment: "must not" is a "should not". The compiler doesn't care what the file extension is. The reason you don't include .cpp files is that files that are supposed to be included are usually called .h and not .cpp. But if you have a file that's supposed to be included and is called .cpp you can go right ahead.

Comment: @user253751 Not being english native, I apologize for this mistake. Corrected, thanks!

Comment: It is nothing to do with English. It is just that: sometimes including a .cpp file makes sense.